# Необходимо в данный код добавить смену картинок по таймеру, а также сделать так, чтобы картинки шли по кругу

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtimer, qstackedwidget, слайд-шоу

Я попытался добавить сюда таймер, но он не работает, при этом никаких ошибок не выдается.

По поводу "карусели" картинок, я пытался это реализовать (в первую очередь заменой цикла `for`), но все это приводило либо к ошибке, либо к тому, что программа зацикливалась на выполнении цикла и просто не открывала окно.

Вот код:

```
import time
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class SlidingStackedWidget(QtWidgets.QStackedWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SlidingStackedWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.m_direction = QtCore.Qt.Horizontal
        self.m_speed = 500
        self.m_animationtype = QtCore.QEasingCurve.OutCubic
        self.m_now = 0
        self.m_next = 0
        self.m_wrap = False
        self.m_pnow = QtCore.QPoint(0, 0)
        self.m_active = False

    def setDirection(self, direction):
        self.m_direction = direction

    def setSpeed(self, speed):
        self.m_speed = speed

    def setAnimation(self, animationtype):
        self.m_animationtype = animationtype

    def setWrap(self, wrap):
        self.m_wrap = wrap

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def slideInPrev(self):
        now = self.currentIndex()
        if self.m_wrap or now > 0:
            self.slideInIdx(now - 1)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def slideInNext(self):
        now = self.currentIndex()
        if self.m_wrap or now < (self.count() - 1):
            self.slideInIdx(now + 1)

    def slideInIdx(self, idx):
        if idx > (self.count() - 1):
            idx = idx % self.count()
        elif idx < 0:
            idx = (idx + self.count()) % self.count()
        self.slideInWgt(self.widget(idx))

    def slideInWgt(self, newwidget):
        if self.m_active:
            return

        self.m_active = True

        _now = self.currentIndex()
        _next = self.indexOf(newwidget)

        if _now == _next:
            self.m_active = False
            return

        offsetx, offsety = self.frameRect().width(), self.frameRect().height()
        self.widget(_next).setGeometry(self.frameRect())

        if not self.m_direction == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            if _now < _next:
                offsetx, offsety = 0, -offsety
            else:
                offsetx = 0
        else:
            if _now < _next:
                offsetx, offsety = -offsetx, 0
            else:
                offsety = 0

        pnext = self.widget(_next).pos()
        pnow = self.widget(_now).pos()
        self.m_pnow = pnow

        offset = QtCore.QPoint(offsetx, offsety)
        self.widget(_next).move(pnext - offset)
        self.widget(_next).show()
        self.widget(_next).raise_()

        anim_group = QtCore.QParallelAnimationGroup(
            self, finished=self.animationDoneSlot
        )

        for index, start, end in zip(
            (_now, _next), (pnow, pnext - offset), (pnow + offset, pnext)
        ):
            animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(
                self.widget(index),
                b"pos",
                duration=self.m_speed,
                easingCurve=self.m_animationtype,
                startValue=start,
                endValue=end,
            )
            anim_group.addAnimation(animation)

        self.m_next = _next
        self.m_now = _now
        self.m_active = True
        anim_group.start(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.DeleteWhenStopped)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def animationDoneSlot(self):
        self.setCurrentIndex(self.m_next)
        self.widget(self.m_now).hide()
        self.widget(self.m_now).move(self.m_pnow)
        self.m_active = False
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

# создайте список каких-то своих изображений        
        self.list_icon = [
            "1.png", "2.png", '3.png',
        ]

        slidingStacked = SlidingStackedWidget()

        for i in self.list_icon:

            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(i))
            
            
            label.setScaledContents(True)
                
            color = QtGui.QColor(*random.sample(range(255), 3))
            label.setStyleSheet(
                "QLabel{ background-color: %s; color : white; font: 40pt}"
                % (color.name(),)
            )
            label.setFixedSize(1920, 540)

            slidingStacked.addWidget(label)



        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer() # создание таймера
        self.timer.setInterval(1000) # установите интервал срабатывания в миллисекундах
        self.timer.setSingleShot(False) # Скажите таймеру что срабатывать надо не один раз, а повторять бесконечно
        self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda: slidingStacked.slideInNext) # При срабатывании таймера вызовем функцию перехода к следующей картинке
        self.timer.start() # теперь можно таймер запустить. Он будет бесконечно крутиться пока работает программа

          
        
        button_prev = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
             "Previous", pressed=slidingStacked.slideInPrev
        )

        button_prev.setFixedSize(71, 41)
        
        
        
        button_next = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
             "Next", pressed=slidingStacked.slideInNext
        )
        button_next.setFixedSize(71, 41)
        

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        

        lay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(central_widget)                  
        lay.addWidget(button_prev, 0, 0)                            
        lay.addWidget(slidingStacked, 0, 1)                          
        lay.addWidget(button_next, 0, 2)                             
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я подправил два момента:

1.

```
# так                               vvvvvv                            vv  но лучше см.ниже
#        self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda: slidingStacked.slideInNext()) 
# или так
        self.timer.timeout.connect(slidingStacked.slideInNext)
```

2. 

```
...
@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def slideInNext(self):
    now = self.currentIndex()
    if self.m_wrap or now < (self.count() - 1):
        self.slideInIdx(now + 1)
# +++    
    else:                                                     # +++
        self.slideInIdx(0)                                    # +++     
...
```

---

```
import time
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class SlidingStackedWidget(QtWidgets.QStackedWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SlidingStackedWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.m_direction = QtCore.Qt.Horizontal
        self.m_speed = 500
        self.m_animationtype = QtCore.QEasingCurve.OutCubic
        self.m_now = 0
        self.m_next = 0
        self.m_wrap = False
        self.m_pnow = QtCore.QPoint(0, 0)
        self.m_active = False

    def setDirection(self, direction):
        self.m_direction = direction

    def setSpeed(self, speed):
        self.m_speed = speed

    def setAnimation(self, animationtype):
        self.m_animationtype = animationtype

    def setWrap(self, wrap):
        self.m_wrap = wrap

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def slideInPrev(self):
        now = self.currentIndex()
        if self.m_wrap or now > 0:
            self.slideInIdx(now - 1)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def slideInNext(self):
        now = self.currentIndex()
        if self.m_wrap or now < (self.count() - 1):
            self.slideInIdx(now + 1)
# +++        
        else:                                                     # +++
            self.slideInIdx(0)                                    # +++      

    def slideInIdx(self, idx):
        if idx > (self.count() - 1):
            idx = idx % self.count()
        elif idx < 0:
            idx = (idx + self.count()) % self.count()
        self.slideInWgt(self.widget(idx))

    def slideInWgt(self, newwidget):
        if self.m_active:
            return

        self.m_active = True

        _now = self.currentIndex()
        _next = self.indexOf(newwidget)

        if _now == _next:
            self.m_active = False
            return

        offsetx, offsety = self.frameRect().width(), self.frameRect().height()
        self.widget(_next).setGeometry(self.frameRect())

        if not self.m_direction == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            if _now < _next:
                offsetx, offsety = 0, -offsety
            else:
                offsetx = 0
        else:
            if _now < _next:
                offsetx, offsety = -offsetx, 0
            else:
                offsety = 0

        pnext = self.widget(_next).pos()
        pnow = self.widget(_now).pos()
        self.m_pnow = pnow

        offset = QtCore.QPoint(offsetx, offsety)
        self.widget(_next).move(pnext - offset)
        self.widget(_next).show()
        self.widget(_next).raise_()

        anim_group = QtCore.QParallelAnimationGroup(
            self, finished=self.animationDoneSlot
        )

        for index, start, end in zip(
            (_now, _next), (pnow, pnext - offset), (pnow + offset, pnext)
        ):
            animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(
                self.widget(index),
                b"pos",
                duration=self.m_speed,
                easingCurve=self.m_animationtype,
                startValue=start,
                endValue=end,
            )
            anim_group.addAnimation(animation)

        self.m_next = _next
        self.m_now = _now
        self.m_active = True
        anim_group.start(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.DeleteWhenStopped)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def animationDoneSlot(self):
        self.setCurrentIndex(self.m_next)
        self.widget(self.m_now).hide()
        self.widget(self.m_now).move(self.m_pnow)
        self.m_active = False
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

# создайте список каких-то своих изображений        
        self.list_icon = [
            "Ok.png", "boy.jpg", 'lena-2.png',
        ]

        slidingStacked = SlidingStackedWidget()

        for i in self.list_icon:

            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(i))
            
            
            label.setScaledContents(True)
                
            color = QtGui.QColor(*random.sample(range(255), 3))
            label.setStyleSheet(
                "QLabel{ background-color: %s; color : white; font: 40pt}"
                % (color.name(),)
            )
            label.setFixedSize(1920, 540)

            slidingStacked.addWidget(label)
     
        button_prev = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
             "Previous", pressed=slidingStacked.slideInPrev
        )
        button_prev.setFixedSize(71, 41)
        
        button_next = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
             "Next", pressed=slidingStacked.slideInNext
        )
        button_next.setFixedSize(71, 41)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        lay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(central_widget)                  
        lay.addWidget(button_prev, 0, 0)                            
        lay.addWidget(slidingStacked, 0, 1)                          
        lay.addWidget(button_next, 0, 2)  


        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()    # создание таймера
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)    # интервал в миллисекундах
#        self.timer.setSingleShot(False) # это по умолчанию

# так                               vvvvvv                            vv  но лучше см.ниже
#        self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda: slidingStacked.slideInNext()) 
# или так
        self.timer.timeout.connect(slidingStacked.slideInNext)

        self.timer.start() # теперь можно таймер запустить. Он будет бесконечно крутиться пока работает программа
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

P.S. Если вы восстановите свой вопрос по данной тематике, который вы удалили, я вам бонусом покажу в нем еще один вариант, который позволит вам лучше освоить данную тему.

Comment: Я все же не до конца понимаю, как работает программа. Можете оставить ресурсы, где я мог бы узнать больше информации?

Comment: @cor3 и это нормально. Все сразу понять и прочувствовать не получится. Должно пройти какое-то время напряженной работы и все станет на свои места. Читайте все подряд, анализируйте все примеры - каждую строчку, так как каждая строка написана не просто так. Лучший ресурс - это документация, но вы также не надейтесь, что сразу правильно будите понимать все что в ней написано. Читайте и перечитывайте и через время возвращайтесь и снова читайте и перечитывайте и пробуйте задуманное реализовывать на конкретных примерах. Удачи вам.